# Teaching AMCL and SLAM

Tags: slam

In trying to explain these important concepts and algorithms it would be super useful to have a video or animation that illustrates through simulation the underlying math. All the videos and articles I can find either are purely conceptual and really simplified (i.e. == magic) or they go deep on the math and go over the heads of most of my students.

Does anyone know of a resource (at the level of a https://www.3blue1brown.com/ to teach AMCL and/or SLAM?

Answer (score 2):

There is no resources like 3blue1brown for SLAM. In general I think you just have to bite the bullet and work through the math and the topics. I recommend the [Freiburg videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6vr3iNrwRA&list=PLgnQpQtFTOGQrZ4O5QzbIHgl3b1JHimN_) and notes on robot mapping.

In regards to a simulation that allows you to step through it I recommend [PythonRobotics](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics). The code examples are quite small and are a good way to see these topics in action with a simple simulation. Since you are interested in ACML there is a basic [particle filter](https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics/blob/master/Localization/particle_filter/particle_filter.py) implementation.